# Microsoft Graph - App is unauthorized to create Sharepoint List subscription

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, sharepoint-list, microsoft-graph-files

I struggle to make app with ClientCredential auth flow to create subscription on SharePoint List.

**Request**:

```
var subscription = new Subscription
{
    ChangeType = "updated",
    NotificationUrl = "{validNotificationUrl}",
    Resource = "sites/root/lists/{listId}",
    ExpirationDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(2),
    ClientState = "{clientState}"
};

subscription = await _graphClient.Subscriptions.Request().AddAsync(subscription);
```

**Response**:

```
Unauthorized 403
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ExtensionError",
    "message": "Operation: Create; Exception: [Status Code: Forbidden; Reason: Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.]",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2020-08-04T13:01:27",
      "request-id": "c480fa5d-4bbd-44a1-9f86-587548a29a19"
    }
}
```

I've checked request access_token, and it has required permissions (*Sites.ReadWrite.All, Sites.Manage.All* according to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions) should be enough).
Reading Subscriptions and creating lists works fine for app.

I started to play around with different configurations, trying to isolate the problem, and managed to:

- make app create subscription on users resource.
- make delegated user create subscription on list

I feel quite lost, since I've given app more permissions than delegated user, and it still gets Unauthorized 403, and response error doesn't tell much how to resolve this issue.

**Are there any configurations for SharePoint List subscriptions that need to be taken care of for app authentication only?**

Comment: how did you get your access token? using a secret or a certificate?

Comment: I'm using client secret to authenticate app for both client credentials and delegated user flows.

Comment: Can you try with a certificate instead? SharePoint APIs in Microsoft graph, and it's own rest APIs require certificate authentication to get the access token for some operations

Comment: I've switched from using client secret to certificate, but with no result. Everything looks the same. I can do requests that I did before, but creating subscription on SP List still returns same error. Maybe request-id (11247f02-e8ff-4a1b-8917-23d6743aa9ee) may be of some use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The service is currently experiencing an issue where app-only lists and drive subscriptions are getting an access denied when it shouldn't. The team is currently working to solve the issue. I suggest you follow [this issue](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/7786) as we investigate the problem or that you open a support ticket asking to link your ticket to the ICM 200246697.